# intersection partition as an orbital partition

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\xi_n$ be the partition of $X$ defined by the equivalence relation $x \sim_n x' \Leftrightarrow (x_{n}, x_{n+1}, \ldots) = (x_{n}', x_{n+1}', \ldots)$. The sequence of partitions $(\xi_n)$ is decreasing and we introduce the intersection partition $\theta= \cap \xi_n$. I'm loooking for a group $G$ of transformations of $X$ such that $\theta$ is the partition into the orbits of $G$.

Maybe my question is somewhat unprecise, I am rather new in ergodic theory. Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: Isn't it true that $\xi_n\subset \xi_{n+1}$? Why do you call this sequence decreasing?

Comment: Provided you mean to union up the equivalence relations, this equivalence relation is often called $E_0$ and can be easily realized as the orbit equivalence relation of the coordinate-wise action of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{< \omega}$ on $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\omega$, or as the equivalence relation generated by addition by one in the $2$-adic integers (except you need to deal with the eventually constant sequences separately).

Comment: The ordering between $\xi_n$ and $\xi_{n+1}$ is not the inclusion. Any element of $\xi_{n}$ is a subset of an element of $\xi_{n+1}$, that is, $\xi_n$ is finer than $\xi_{n+1}$, or $\xi_{n+1}$ is coarser than $\xi_n$. It is sensible to denote $\xi_n \geq \xi_{n+1}$ because it is more naturel to say that the smallest (coarsest) partition is the trivial partition $\{\varnothing, X\}$ and the biggest (finest) partition is ${\cal P}(X)$.

Comment: @Stephane: Yes, I figured that out. That means I understood your question correctly. 

Comment: @Clinton: That was my first choice too, but dealing with eventually constant sequences is not easy. 

Comment: I agree that writing down a formula is somewhat annoying, but it's not so horrible to biject each of those two orbits with the integers.  But more importantly, if it's a context in which countable sets may safely be ignored, it provides a quick answer.

Comment: @Clinton: Could you confirm that the coordinate-wise action is the sum $x \to x+g$ ? Actually I am interest in the equality $\theta(x)=Gx$ for almost all $x \in X$ (for a suitable measure on $X$), hence the constant sequences are easy to deal with.

Comment: I guess since the question is related to ergodic theory, then the group should acts by continuous transformations and measure 0 subsets can be ignored. Then the odometer transformation (defined by Clinton) should be OK. 

Comment: There is a whole subject of Borel classification/ equivalence relations. See for instance Kechris' monograph ["*The theory of countable Borel
equivalence relations*"](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/lectures%20on%20CBER01.pdf). The above is called tail equivalence relation. It occurs very frequently. Very roughly speaking, this is the simplest equivalence relation among those that strictly more complicated (in terms of Borel reduction) than the equality equivalence relation on the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the group $G_n$ of all permutations of strings $\{0,1\}^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$ of length $n$. That group acts on the set of all strings $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ in the natural way (it changes the $n$-prefix only). Now clearly $G_n\subset G_{n+1}$ for every $n$. Let $G=\cup G_n$. It is a (locally finite) group which acts on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the orbit equivalence relation is your $\theta$ (if I understood the question correctly): two strings are in the same orbit iff they coincide almost everywhere.

Comment: This does not seem quite right; for example $01^\infty$ is not in the same orbit as $1^\infty$ under the action you propose.  The orbit equivalence relation generated by your action is strictly finer than eventual agreement.

Comment: Yes, it is. $G_n$ is not the permutation group of indices, it is the permutation group of the set of strings of length $n$. 

Comment: So $|G_n|=(2^n)!$.

Comment: Oops, sorry for misreading that.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: @Mark: what do you mean by two strings coinciding almost everywhere ?

Comment: @Stephane: It means they differ only at finite number of coordinates, i.e. $x_m=x_m'$ for all $m$ greater than some $m_0$. 

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Thank you Mark & Clinton. I will probably ask more precise related questions soon ;)